# How can I use an SSLStream without a TcpSocket

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl

I have written a TCP library and now want to support SSL.  The library separates the connect/disconnect part from the processing of the data stream. I am able to slot in a stream handler which will transmit and receive chunks of bytes, but it doesn't have access to the socket that supplies that data.

All the examples of using SslStream look pretty much like this:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
Sslstream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), true, ValidCerts);
```

I want to use SslStream without a TcpClient supplying the stream.

Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Put whatever stream you have into `SslStream` constructor instead of `client.GetStream`. If that doesn't work - show the code and how exactly it doesn't work (exception details).

Comment: How well do you understand SSL/TLS? You should take a peek at [RFC 5246](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246) do get an idea of what is needed in terms of network activity.

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking about this too much, but I would have thought you would need 2 streams (egress, ingress), otherwise the bytes coming in would overwrite the bytes going out.

Comment: a NetworkStream really is two streams, in that the write methods give you egress and the read methods give you ingress. In Java the comparable methods are `Socket.getInputStream()` and `Socket.getOutputStream()` which makes the distinction perhaps more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The example can be rewritten as:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
Stream stream = client.GetStream();
...
SslStream ssl = new SslStream(stream, true, ValidCerts);
```

The `client.GetStream()` call was just inlined; `SslStream` only interacts with a `Stream`, not with a `TcpClient`.

Comment: I don't want to use a TcpClient stream, I want to create my own Stream.

Comment: `TcpClient.GetStream()` returns a `NetworkStream`, but you could use _any_ `Stream` implementation.

Comment: If I supply a ``MemoryStream`` it doesn't seem to work.  Do you think it should?

Comment: When authenticating, `SslStream` will probably first write handshake data to the `MemoryStream`. You have to respond to the handshake written to the stream, but you don't have time to prepare the stream since it will immediately start trying to read from that same `MemoryStream`, which will immediately return 0, which is treated as a closed connection.